# "populate" a field with a $lookup without overwriting the existing value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider the following documents:

**A `communications` document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c069a6acbd69e0f61983850"),
    "type" : "request",
    "title" : "test 1",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "authorId" : "7b0dcd22-c3bb-426f-8235-671b82acee98",
            "body" : "test 1",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-12-04T15:16:58.342Z")
        }
    ],
    "receivers" : [ 
        "e75f3849-09bb-46a4-a05d-885b6d31ccc3"
    ]
}
```

**A `users` document**

```
{
    "_id" : "7b0dcd22-c3bb-426f-8235-671b82acee98",
    "userInfo" : {
        "avatarKey" : "7b0dcd22-c3bb-426f-8235-671b82acee98/avatars/Dandelion.png",
        "familyName" : "Doe",
        "givenName" : "John"
    }
}
```

In the **mongo shell**, I try to retrieve the `communications` with the `messages.authorId` "populated" with the `userInfo` fields of my `user`document.

I tried to do it with a `$lookup` like this :

```
db.communications.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "users",
         localField: "messages.authorId",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "messages.authorId"
       }
  }
])
```

But the field `messages.authorId` is overwritten.

How can I "populate" my `userInfo` field without replacing the existing values ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `messages` is an array field it overwrites  the existing array with the new object as you provide the `.dot` notation in the **`as`** (`"messages.authorId"`) expression.

So if you want to populate each user inside `messages` the array You need to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `messages` array first to add a new key and then [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to roll back again into array.

```
db.communications.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$messages" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "messages.authorId",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "messages.authorId"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$messages.authorId" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "messages": { "$push": "$messages" },
    "type": { "$first": "$type" },
    "title": { "$first": "$title" },
    "receivers": { "$first": "$receivers" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its really helpful. But I've one more level depth in the same structure. let say

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c069a6acbd69e0f61983850"),
    "type" : "request",
    "title" : "test 1",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "authorId" : "7b0dcd22-c3bb-426f-8235-671b82acee98",
            "body" : "test 1",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-12-04T15:16:58.342Z"),
            "something": ["array of ref ids"]
        }
    ],
    "receivers" : [ 
        "e75f3849-09bb-46a4-a05d-885b6d31ccc3"
    ]
}

& now I want to populate something ids

Comment: @ShivamVerma Please open another question. I will try to help you.